# Encrypting with RSA, what's the best practice to store the public key?

Tags: javascript, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I was developing an hybrid app where I used RSA to encrypt the communication. I then stored the public key inside an element in index.html like some library suggested, and read the public key from there. It was fine by me as no one could access the key unless he could get the compiled app file.

Now I wish to use the same method of encryption on the web, and I don't feel like adding the public key to the html.

I wonder what's the best practice with storing the RSA public key without hardcoding it in the html or js files?

Much thanks for any advice!

Comment: If you want end to end security from a web page to your server, use the HTTPs built into the browser to protect the transmission to your server.

Comment: I would, I just want to use an extra security layer...

Comment: you already have the SSL, no need for more complexity, it is almost useless to do it with javascript https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Interesting read... thanks

Comment: @Shay: since the key is public, you can safely expose it in html/js. Just learning the key doesn't allow anyone to misuse it, your private key is still safe on the server. And still, please reconsider your approach as noted by Mi-Creativity.

Comment: Like @Mi-Creativity said, if you only want an additional security layer between client and server then this is completely unnecessary. But if you want to secure the client to client communication passing through the server, then this is a valid request. Anyway, this question can only be answered with personal preference if no other constraints are known.